# Button that updates number on all sessions

Tags: javascript

I've tried a lot of ways, like for example the `fs` module, but I just can't find out how to implement this. I need a button that:

- Updates by one whenever **any user** presses the button
- Persists on the server

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: where is your attempts? If we can't see your work, we can't help you

Comment: What have you tried? You realize you can not do this on front alone? Simplest is to on a click push a request to server which informs the server to increment some value by 1. If you do it like that, server doesn't mind which user sent the request it will keep serving (increasing by 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new and need to build something that stores stuff on the server you have a lot to learn. If you just need to solve this simple problem and get things working you could make huge progress using a hosted backend service. If you do this you can write a couple of lines in JS and the job will be done. Most offer a free account.

One such service is built.io see link below:

https://docs.built.io/api-reference

```
var project = Built.App('blt5d4sample2633b').Class('score').Object();
project = project.increment('points',10); //Increases points field value by 10
```

That code above would update the score by 10 and store it , you can then retreive it when you show the page. All users would see the score update.

There are realtime backend services too which are very good.

An example is:

[www.firebase.com](http://www.firebase.com)

You would need to decide which one is best for you, add their script to your page add a button, hook the click event upto a function that you would then add the simple code to update the score. See above.

It a nutshell that would be it. You can probably get it working in under 1 hour if you follow the guides on the vendors site.

[Firebase](http://www.firebase.com) is backed by google and has a huge online community.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :)